# How to retrieve value for a key from a list of dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like the one below:

```
test_1 = [{'path': 'remote_path'}, {'dir': 'local_dir'}]
```

I used the following to retrieve the value

```
print (list(map(itemgetter('path'), test_1)))
```

However when I run this it gives me the following error : KeyError: 'path'

Any idea what I might be doing wrong or I am using it in an incorrect way.

Comment: Does my answer help you :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get the error because the second dictionary doesn't have the key `path`.
A simple method:

```
print([i['path'] for i in test_1 if 'path' in i][0])
```

Here the condition check for the existence of the key.

Comment: yes I know of that but wanted to avoid the for loop thing.

Comment: @Mustufain added a one-liner

Comment: @Mustufain try now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *get* method.

```
for d in test_1:
    if d.get('path') is not None:
        print(d['path'])
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `lambda`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x.get('path'), test_1)))
```

If the dict has the key `path`.It will return the value.If not,it will return None.
Result:

```
['remote_path', None]
```